# How to fill a JS Highcharts chart in Angular with a custom array

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, loops, highcharts

I try to use the Highcharts JS library with Angular.
I use the [Column Drilldown model](https://www.highcharts.com/demo/column-drilldown).

**GOAL :**

The data part of the graph must look like this :

```
data: [{
  name: 'text name',
  y: 5,
  drilldown: 'text name'
}]
```

My goal is to fill that data part with an array instead of manually typing .

**DATA :**

My array looks like this :

```
var arr = { "Type1": 1.44, "Type2": 0.64, "Type3": 0.20, "Type4": 1.70 }
```

So the Highcharts data part should become:

```
 data: [{
      name: 'Type1',
      y: 1.44,
      drilldown: 'Type1'
    },
{
      name: 'Type2',
      y: 0.64,
      drilldown: 'Type2'
    },
{
      name: 'Type3',
      y: 0.20,
      drilldown: 'Type3'
    },
{
      name: 'Type4',
      y: 1.70,
      drilldown: 'Type4'
    }
]
```

**WORK IN PROGRESS :**

I tried to build a array called *myarray* as follows :

```
var myarray = [];

for (const [a, b] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  myarray.push("{name:'" + a + "', y:" +b + ", drilldown:'" + a + "'}")
}
```

It returns :

```
["{name:'Type1', y:1.44, drilldown:'Type1'}", "{name:'Type2', y:0.64,
drilldown:'Type2'}", "{name:'Type3', y:0.2, drilldown:'Type3'}",
"{name:'Type4', y:1.7, drilldown:'Type4'}"]
```

... that does not completely fit to the Highcharts syntax. I tried it...

```
    data: [
      myarray
    ]
```

... and it indeed fails. Maybe it's because of the apostrophes ?
Do you how to correct it to make the chart work ?
Please see my tries on that [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/31bp8ejc/).

Any help would be very appreciated, thanks !

Comment: Try with template literals:   `'{name: "${a}", y: "${b}", drilldown: "${a}"}'`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the library you are using but I realize that the syntax that *data* expects is an *Array< Object>* and you are building the variable *myArray* as an *Array< string>*.
I suggest changing the code snippet:

```
for (const [a, b] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  myarray.push("{name:'" + a + "', y:" +b + ", drilldown:'" + a + "'}")
}
```

for:

```
for (const [a, b] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  myarray.push({name: a, y:b , drilldown:a })
}
```

then *data* can receive *myArray* like this:

```
data: myarray
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to create an array of objects, not an array of strings. For example:

```
for (const [a, b] of Object.entries(arr)) {
  myarray.push({
    name: a,
    y: b,
    drilldown: a
  })
}

Highcharts.chart('container', {
  series: [{
    ...,
    data: myarray
  }],
  ...
});
```

---

**Live demo:** https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/bhsw42r9/

**API Reference:** https://api.highcharts.com/highcharts/series.column.data